# SQL string before and after certain characters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT NAME 
FROM SERVERS
```

returns:

```
SDACR.hello.com  
SDACR 
SDACR\AIR
SDACR.hello.com\WATER
```

I need the `SELECT` query for below result:

```
SDACR  
SDACR  
SDACR\AIR
SDACR\WATER
```

Kindly help ! I tried using LEFT and RIGHT functions as below, but not able to get combined output correctly:

```
 SELECT 
     LEFT(Name, CHARINDEX('.', Name) - 1) 
 FROM 
     SERVERS     

SELECT 
    RIGHT(Name, LEN(Name) - CHARINDEX('\', Name)) 
FROM
    SERVERS
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a **specific** problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're just trying to `REPLACE` a substring of characters in your column. You should try this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(Name,'.hello.com','') AS ReplacementName
FROM SERVERS
```

Comment: This worked now. I actually used Replace function earlier, however there were multiple strings to be ignored like 'hello.com' and 'hi.com'. I was not aware of excluding both together.  thanks for your help.

SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(Name,'.hello.com',''),'hi.com','') AS ReplacementName
FROM SERVERS

Answer (score 0):

In tsql, you can concatenate values with `CONCAT()`, or you can simply add strings together with `+`.

```
SELECT LEFT(Name, CHARINDEX('.',Name)-1) + RIGHT(Name,LEN(Name)-CHARINDEX('\',Name)) from SERVERS
```

Also, be careful with doing arithmetic with `CHARINDEX()`. A value without a '.' or a '\' will return a `NULL` and you will get an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEFT` for this to select everything up to the first period (dot) and add on everything after the last `\`

```
declare @servers table ([NAME] varchar(64))
insert into @servers
values
('SDACR.hello.com '),
('SDACR'), 
('SDACR\AIR'),
('SDACR.hello.com\WATER')

select 
    left([NAME],case when charindex('.',[NAME]) = 0 then len([NAME]) else charindex('.',[NAME]) -1 end) + 
    case when charindex('\',left([NAME],case when charindex('.',[NAME]) = 0 then len([NAME]) else charindex('.',[NAME]) -1 end)) = 0 then right([NAME],charindex('\',reverse([NAME]))) else '' end
from @servers
```

Comment: wow....this is great....thank you.....though i got it working by using the REPLACE function twice. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Throwing my hat in.... Showing how to use Values and APPLY for cleaner code.

```
-- sample data in an easily consumable format
declare @yourdata table (txt varchar(100));
insert @yourdata values 
('SDACR.hello.com'),
('SDACR'),
('SDACR\AIR'),
('SDACR.hello.com\WATER');

-- solution
select 
  txt, 
  newTxt = 
  case 
    when loc.dot = 0 then txt
    when loc.dot > 0 and loc.slash = 0 then substring(txt, 1, loc.dot-1)
    else substring(txt, 1, loc.dot-1) + substring(txt, loc.slash, 100)
  end
from @yourdata
cross apply (values (charindex('.',txt), (charindex('\',txt)))) loc(dot,slash);
```

**Results**

```
txt                            newTxt
------------------------------ --------------------
SDACR.hello.com                SDACR
SDACR                          SDACR
SDACR\AIR                      SDACR\AIR
SDACR.hello.com\WATER          SDACR\WATER
```